# Does slf4j use commons-logging implementation by default?

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, apache-commons-logging

I have only worked with `log4j` in the past.  Now I am scouting a new project and noticing that it uses `slf4j 1.7.2`.  I understand it is only an API specification which provides a simplified interface (AKA facade) to various implementations that conform to it, such as [java.util.logging, log4j and logback](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html).  However, I noticed that `commons-logging` wasn't mentioned in the list on the API web site, however, its jar was in this app's classpath.  When I removed it from the classpath to check whether it was the used implemetation, I confirmed that it indeed was:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
```

Is commons-logging indeed the default implementation for slf4j?  Because their documentation says:

**If no binding is found on the class path, then SLF4J will default to a no-operation implementation.**

at the above linked page.  And even though I have `slf4j-nop-1.7.2.jar` in the classpath, which I am guessing the default implementation referred to above is, I still get the exception asking for `org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory` if the commons is not in the classpath, so I am confused.

A clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: My guess would be that some other dependency you have is pulling in commons-logging. If you're using maven or a similar build tool, you should be able to visualise your dependency tree and see what's including commons-logging.

Comment: actually, I am using Ant

Answer (score 0):

You need a combination of the binding jar AND the logging implementation (JCL in this case) on the classpath.

[Binding with a logging framework at deployment time](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html#swapping)

commons-logging is not the default, but if you have slf4j-jcl-1.7.2.jar on your classpath, it will try to use that.  So if you therefore remove JCL from your path, it will complain that it can't find the classes.

slf4j-nop-1.7.2.jar is the no-op "SLF4J bindings" jar, not an implementation in itself.

Comment: unfortunately, when I added `slf4j-jcl-1.7.2.jar`, it still complained about not finding commons

Comment: what i had in the classpath was:  `slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar` and `slf4j-jcl-1.7.2.jar`

Comment: But do you have `commons-logging-1.1.1.jar` in your classpath? `slf4j-jcl-1.7.2.jar` tells SLF4J to use commons-logging, but if you don't have the actual commons-logging jar in your path, it won't work.